# $routeProvider: templateUrl requests with X-Requested-With header

Tags: ajax, angularjs, route-provider

`jQuery.ajax()` normally sends an `X-Requested-With` header with `XMLHttpRequest` set as the content. On the server (in PHP), I usually detect this by testing:

`$is_ajax = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest'`

In [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), commonly found in `$routeProvider.when()`, you can obtain a template from the server with `templateUrl: '/path/on/server'`.

**My problem is** that `templateUrl` requests seem to *not* set `X-Requested-With` headers, so there's no way to distinguish `templateUrl` requests from any other type of request.

**Is there any way to get `$routeProvider` to send `X-Requested-With` as `XMLHttpRequest`?**

*Reference:*

- [$routeProvider Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider) - (search `templateUrl`)
- [jQuery jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax1) - see `jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")`
- Using Angular `v1.1.5` via [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#angularjs)
- *Update:* I found the [actual commit](http://gitelephant.cypresslab.net/angular-js/commit/3a75b1124d062f64093a90b26630938558909e8d) where Angular developers removed `X-Requested-With` from `$http.get`. Wonder why they would do that?
- *Update:* https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1004 - discussion where header was removed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tip of the hat to **Zerot** in FreeNode's [#angularjs](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=angularjs&uio=d4)

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/path/on/server',
        controller: 'Ctrl'
    });
});
```

Edit: to be more specific, this is the line you need somewhere:

`$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';`